# Conditions on non-divisibilty of a product

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. What should be the conditions on $m,n$ such that $d\nmid mn$ for all $m+n\leq d< mn$. Is there an easy way to describe such natural numbers?

Note: If $m,n$ are distinct prime numbers, then they satisfy the above conditions. Similarly one can find some other special cases easily, but it seems one needs to consider a lot of cases.

Note: Requiring $(m,n)=1$ is not enough, for example $105=21\times 5$ but 35 divides 105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $n \leqslant m$. Let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $mn$. Then the condition is precisely

$$\frac{mn}{p} < m+n \iff \frac1p < \frac1n + \frac1m.$$

Since $$\frac1n + \frac1m \leqslant \frac2n,$$

we must have $n < 2p$, and thus either $n = p$ - in which case the condition holds - or $n$ is a prime between $p$ and $2p$. If $p$ is odd, we have

$$\frac{2}{p(p+2)} = \frac1p - \frac{1}{p+2} \leqslant \frac1p - \frac1n \overset{!}{<} \frac1m = \frac{1}{kp},$$

which means $k < \frac{p+2}{2} < p$, and that contradicts the minimality of $p$. So the only further possibility is $p = 2$ and $n = 3$, which leads to m = 4.

So the condition is satisfied if and only if $\{m,n\} = \{3,4\}$, or one of $\{m,n\}$ is the smallest prime divisor of $mn$.